# How to make type="date" work on all browsers

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have added input type="date" but it is supported only in chrome. Other browsers do not support the date picker. Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Look for a polyfill - https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this

[Cross browser datepicker](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-create-cross-browser-datepickers-in-minutes--net-20236)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the [datapicker plugin by jQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). It is a highly configurable plugin which you can configure date format and language, restrict the selectable date ranges and add in buttons and other navigation options easily, but be aware that creating a datepicker on an `<input type="date">` is **not supported** due to a UI conflict with the native picker, but all major browsers **is supported** by jQueryUI datepicker.

So if you go with this solution make a input type text, or a div or span if you would like an inline calendar.

**How to configure jQueryUI datepicker?**

Make a element which you want to be a datepicker

```
<input type="text" name="date" class="date" value="" />
```

In JavaScript refer to that element and make it into a datepicker, then pass whatever [supported options](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#quick-nav) you would like to use.

```
$(function() {
    // Target the text input elements with the class date
    var dateElem = $('.date');
    // Make it into a datepicker
    dateElem.datepicker({
        // Pass options
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

Here is a fully functional example of jQuery UI datepickers in action: http://jsfiddle.net/et0g0tn5/1/

Comment: What do you mean by "its not working" ?

Comment: i have implement the same but it is not working

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. it is working perfectly fine.